# In SPARK, how is caching dataframe helpful when the frame is getting used only once

Tags: performance, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

> I understand that if the same dataframe is getting used at multiple places then caching a dataframe is of huge help.

With my recent code change in **SPARK**, when I added cache to a dataframe which is used just once, I found there was an improvement in performance. How is calling `cache()` on a dataframe helpful, if the dataframe is getting used only **once**. I.e. the program has only one action on that dataframe. How does this help?

```scala
...
val tableDataDF = spark.sql(query)
tableDataDF.cache() // adding this line improves lot of performance (hours gets reduced to min)


tableDataDf.write.mode("append").jdbc(url, table, prop)
...
```

The above Dataframe holds around 10-15L records.

Comment: Hi Mintu, you should read this post on how to ask questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. For instance, provide the minimal amount of code necessary for people to be able to understand what you are doing and reproduce it if needs be.

Comment: Hi @Oli, I have updated the question. I'm trying to save the dataframe to database. Code snippet added. Thanks

Comment: I imagine `cache()` forces materializing all of the table data in memory before writing, and it's written in a single batch. Maybe without it each row is computed just in time for writing, and the rows are added one at a time. That's just a guess, though.